# Design Pattern decisions - REST API & DAL

Tags: c#, api, design-patterns, factory-pattern, command-pattern

I am working on application that has WCF REST API and below some DAL. Everything is written in C#.

All REST methods are GET, but many of them have generic string parameter (among other params)  that I parse and map to a list object. It works well.

When it comes to mapping to Dto object I would like to use some design pattern to instantiate correct Dto based on mapped REST params. Not sure is it possible since I have that generic string parameter (param name will not be the same all the time) ?

Also, based on created Dto type I would like to choose appropriate DB method to call, command design pattern for this one, I guess?

Thanks for help,
I could explain more if needed.

Comment: DAL is the class library currently referenced by Service layer

Comment: `generic string parameter` are filters and sort conditions? Also, `All REST methods are GET` are they all safe methods that don't change resource state of REST app?

Comment: @nikita  yes and yes.

I don't use ORM so filters are string params that I handle manually

Comment: @user1073210 then why you don't use OData?

Comment: @user1073210 If you don't want to use ORM then you can use ReflectionProvider that is shipped with WCF Data Services. If you don't want to use Odata you can take query syntax from it and use Linq2Rest library that gives you capability of transferring Odata query into LINQ expression.

Comment: @nikita  Thanks, this sounds helpful. I will take a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

The key line in the question is this:

> ...design pattern to instantiate correct Dto based on mapped REST params

To me this sounds like you want to use the [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

Urgh. Yes I know, cargo cult programming etc, BUT(!), there are good reasons:

- You want to intialise a class (the DAL) based upon *some settings*
- You want those settings defined at the top level (REST mapping)
- You want lower level code to be totally ignorant of the settings (right?) so that they can change arbitrarily without requiring system wide refactors.

Sure, you could always just pass an instance of the DAL down the stack but that isn't always possible and can get a bit scrappy.

### Alternatively...

Consider creating a DAL implementation that can be made aware of the various switches and will [delegate](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html) calls to the correct DAL implementation. This might actually be lighter weight than a straight up factory.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed same kind of application (WCF REST service).

I have created .net solution and added below project

- BusinessLayer
- DataAcessLayer
- DataService (WCF Service)
- EntityLayer

DataService:

```
 public SnapshotData GetSnapshot(string symbol, int nocache)
    {
        SnapshotData objSnapshotData;
        try
        {
                objSnapshotData = (new SnapshotBAL()).GetSanpshotData(symbol);
                SerializeObject(objSnapshotData, localCacheKey);

            return objSnapshotData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

BusinessLayer:

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
public class SnapshotBAL
{
    public Snapshot GetSanpshot(string symbol)
    {
        return (new SnaapshotDAL()).GetSanpshot(symbol);
    }       
}
}
```

EntiryLayer:

```
namespace EntityLayer
{
public class Snapshot
{

    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
 }
}
```

DataAccessLayer:

```
namespace DataAccessLayer
{
public class SnaapshotDAL : PrototypeDB
{
    public Snapshot GetSanpshot(string symbol)
    {
        AddParameter("o_snapshot");
        AddParameter("i_symbol", symbol);

        Snapshot objSanapshot = new Snapshot();

        return ObjectHelper.FillObject<Snapshot>(typeof(Snapshot), GetReader("A_SM7_V1_P.GetSnapshotQuick"));
    }
}
}
```